# How to minify angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, gulp, gulp-uglify

There is a problem,i want to minify the angular.js, not my personal code but the angular library file --angular.js,
I used gulp-uglify to minify it , here is the gulp code:

```
gulp.task('angularjsmin', function () {
gulp.src(['lib/angular/angular.js']) 
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(contact("angular.min.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/lib/angular'));
```

});

It worked in morden browser , but it's unuse in IE8.
The angular version is 1.2.29, it's support IE8,
but the file "angular.min.js" which i minified is not support IE8, and when use it in IE8,the browser tell me that "Missing identify" and "angular is  undefined". Is there any other methods to minify the angular.js? How can i solve this problem?Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to minify it yourself? Can't you use the already minified version? https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.29/angular.min.js

Comment: What error are you exactly receiving when you run your build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CDN in order to delivery common libraries like angular or jquery, you will avoid possible headache of build it yourself. If you do not have a specific reasons and advantage to do so, a CDN is the good way to go.

Some major libraries are hosted on CDN for free on very reliable servers like Google offers:

https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

and you can simply include the library in your code as:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>`

The main advantage of a CDN is an increase in the speed on which the content is delivered to the users.

Some advantages are:

- Lower server load.
- Increase in concurrent users on server.
- Geo-location.
- User may have already downloaded the library (cached previously in browser).

But if you really want to build yourself try reading the following tutorial:
https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute

Comment: I have to minify it myself because i have modified the source codes.

Comment: I have modified the time picker ,it used english and i changed it into chinese.

Comment: I used Closure Compiler to minify the angular.js, It worked in IE8, awsome! Could you please tell that why it worked and why the file minified by gulp-uglify was not worked?

Comment: Read this article you need to grunt / bower and npm https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/contribute#building-angularjs

Comment: I have accepted your answer , thank you .And i haven't use grunt / bower and npm , i have used gulp to build my project and i just want to minify angular.js . And i succeed by your help .And now ,could you please tell me the difference of gulp-uglify and Closure Compiler, why angular.min.js minified by Closure Compiler could use in IE8?

Comment: They are two different minigier, gulp-uglify uses uglify-js when Closure Compiler use it own engine. They have different set of features and some time the could result in different code optimization.

Comment: I get it , thanks .Do you have the source code of Closure Compiler？